# Creating elements on DOM dynamically but form not sending anything

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a form which has some of its fields dynamically added based on another field, I was able to make it create the elements, but when I send the form, none of those are sent with the non dynamically fields that are loaded on page load.

Here's how I'm adding

```
function foo(field) {
var selectionDiv = document.getElementById("div_" + field);

var divLength = selectionDiv.children.length;
for (var i = 0; i < divLength; i++) {
    if (selectionDiv.children[i].id.indexOf(field) != -1) {
        var element = document.createElement(selectionDiv.children[i].tagName);
        element.setAttribute("type", selectionDiv.children[i].type);
        element.setAttribute("value", selectionDiv.children[i].value);
        element.setAttribute("id", selectionDiv.children[i].id);
        if (selectionDiv.children[i].className != "") {
            element.setAttribute("class", selectionDiv.children[i].className);
        }
        $(element).appendTo("#div_" + field);
    }
}
}
```

The HTML after insertion:

```
<form action="/URL" id="form" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="Confirmation('Are you sure?');return false;"><div class="form-horizontal">
<...OtherFields...>
<div class="form-group" id="form_group_test">
<label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="Identity">test:</label>
<div class="col-xs-4" id="div_test">
        <input id="Fields_test__Identity" name="Fields[test].Identity" type="hidden" value="test">
        <input class="form-control hasTooltip" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" id="Fields_test__Value" name="Fields[test].Value" title="" type="text" value="*">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="foo('test'); return false;" class="btn btn-default hasTooltip form-control" data_toggle="tooltip" data_placement="right" title=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus blue"></span></button>
        <input type="hidden" value="test" id="Fields_test1__Identity"><input type="text" value="*" id="Fields_test1__Value" class="form-control hasTooltip"></div>
<...MoreFields...>
</form>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a closing form tag where you've edited out "MoreFields"

Comment: FYI, `$('<' + selectionDiv.children[i].tagName + '>', selectionDiv.children[i]).appendTo("#div_" + field);` may achieve most of the work for you instead of using createElement and setAttribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating dynamically the element, the attribute "name" is missing, try the following code:

```
function foo(field) {
var selectionDiv = document.getElementById("div_" + field);

var divLength = selectionDiv.children.length;
for (var i = 0; i < divLength; i++) {
    if (selectionDiv.children[i].id.indexOf(field) != -1) {
        var element = document.createElement(selectionDiv.children[i].tagName);
        element.setAttribute("type", selectionDiv.children[i].type);
        element.setAttribute("value", selectionDiv.children[i].value);
        element.setAttribute("id", selectionDiv.children[i].id);
        element.setAttribute("name", selectionDiv.children[i].id);
        if (selectionDiv.children[i].className != "") {
            element.setAttribute("class", selectionDiv.children[i].className);
        }
        $(element).appendTo("#div_" + field);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice catch! I thought the id attribute would be enogh =)